# Custom Callout - ViewDidLoad - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class for a map pin callout in Swift app, which connects to a .xib file. I am trying to change to text of a label inside of the view when the user clicks on the pin an the view loads. Here is what I have I have:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class CustomCallout: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        testLabel.text = "test"
    }


    override func hitTest( point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let viewPoint = superview?.convertPoint(point, toView: self) ?? point
        //let isInsideView = pointInside(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        let view = super.hitTest(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        return view
    }


    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point)
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

With this line being highlighted:

```
testLabel.text = "test"
```

How do I get this to work? How can I change the text of an outlet when this callout view loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference to it: [CustomView](https://gist.github.com/bwhiteley/049e4bede49e71a6d2e2)
You can create customview with list steps below:

- First you create subclass for custom view.
- Click to xib file set `File's Owner` to this class.
- Drage view to class and set it is `contentView`, drag all element you want to class too.
- And in class add this code:

  ```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
     self.commonInit()
  } 

  private func commonInit() {
      NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CutomViewDemo", owner: self, options: nil)
      guard let content = contentView else { return }
      content.frame = self.bounds
      content.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
     self.addSubview(content)
  }
  ```

Now and you can use customView. You can check my demo: [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoCustomViewSwift)

Comment: Thank you! Should I try to set the label text inside of private func commonInit() ?

Comment: no, you just do like this gist, it will auto set for you.

Comment: When I tap on the pin now, the app crashes, I get the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

Comment: @KatieH maybe you load wrong, I will create demo and explain it for you. Wait me.